# declared Lock object in Another Class and invoke lock's method in another class

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I declared a `Lock` Object in class `A` , and I invoke that locks's method in class `B`.

```
public class A{
  final Lock accessLock = new ReentrantLock(true);
  final Condition canexe = accessLock.newCondition();
  B b = new B(this);

  {
    b.methodToLock();
  }
}

public class B{
  A a ;

  public B(A a){
    this.a = a;
  }

  public void methodToLock(){
    a.accessLock.lock();
  }
}
```

Which object will be locked?

- the object of class A ?
- the object of class B ?

Comment: I made some changes to your code to make it compile. There were multiple issues with it. Can you verify if - *what I made of it* - matches with your intentions ? - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object that is actually locked is the `accessLock` instance. Any thread trying to acquire the lock **on the same instance** will block, regardless of which class it comes from.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is some error with the code as `lock` is a method:

```
public class B {
    A a = new A();
    public void methodToLock(){
        a.accessLock.lock();

    }
}
```

Here you are trying to acquire the lock using a reference `accessLock` to `ReentrantLock` in the class A. So actually you are getting lock on that particular instance of class A which is declared in class B. If you create new instance of class A then that will not be locked using same lock. Also it has no locking on any instance of class B or even class B itself.

It means if multiple threads are trying to modify the instance `a` in this class they will be blocked accordingly.